# Package xurl not found

Tags: packages, texlive

I need a package `xurl` and not found in TeXstudio.

[image]

I use TeX Live Manager 2016 and I want to install manually but not found.

[image]

How to solve this problem?

Comment: upgrade to newer TeX live version? 2016 is long ago, older than that package.

Comment: Ok, I try to upgrade into new version of TeXLive

Comment: Did you try the packet manager tlmgr? https://tug.org/texlive/doc/tlmgr.html

Comment: No, I didn't try it. Now I upgrade TeX live version.